# Spring batch CompletionPolicy based on item fields

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to implement CompletionPolicy in which I need to decide completion based on some filed for example let say my item is a order class and I need to add up order amount and once amount is more than 1000 I want chunk to complete.
ordeer.amount

but in CompletionPolicy i never get item.Is there another way to achieve it?
or i can get item in CompletionPolicy somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `CompletionPolicy` implement `ItemReadListener` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemReadListener.html). You can get access to the items through the `ItemReadListener.afterRead` method.

In contrast to other standard batch components like readers, processors, writers and tasklet, a completion policy implementing a listener interface does *not* get registered automatically.

So you'll need to register your completion policy explicitly as a listener.

Comment: completion policy need no to be added as listener just add as chunk-completion-policy="customCompletionPolicy" in you chunk. and thanks for the suggetion I am implementing same way.but keeping completionPolicy and ItemreaderListner Separate.