# Spring batch - Chunk size not respected when filtering in processor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to setup a spring batch to run with a fixed chunk size, but with filtering in the processor.

The issue i'm facing is that the chunk's size varies in function of what is filtered. In some cases, the number of items filtered is equal to the chunk size, which results in the writer being called with 0 items, and also end up doing more database calls.

Here is my step definition:

```kotlin
val step = stepBuilderFactory
    .get("job")
    .chunk<Item, Item>(50) // The number of items I want to write
    .reader(reader)
    .processor(processor) // Sometimes, all items are filtered
    .writer(writer) // This is called with 0 items
    .build()
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a batch size of always 50 **WHEN WRITING**. I have been looking for this everywhere, and I can't seem to find how to do it.

I saw that there is a method

```java
public <I, O> SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> chunk(CompletionPolicy completionPolicy)
```

I tried to implement a custom completion policy, but I'm not really sure I understand how it works, or if it's even possible to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763171/spring-batch-completionpolicy-based-on-item-fields
In your case you could implement `ItemProcessListener` instead, and count the non-null results in `afterProcess`.

Comment: So i would register the class as an `item process listener` and a `completion policy`? I guess that would work. I will try that.